# How do I have both my drop down list divs sit side by side to each other

Tags: html, css, position

Cant seem to get these two lists to sit side by side rather than on top of each other , here is my code, any guidance would be much appreciated!
Here is my code

```
<div class="panel-body">

                <div class="monthSelect">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="yearValues">Select Year</label><br /> <!--Delete if necessary-->


                    <div class="yearSelector" >
                        <select ng-model="selected.year" ng-options="year.year for year in yearValues">
                        <option value="" disabled>Select year</option>

                        </select><!--Select ng-model-->
                             </div><!--YearSelector Div-->

                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Select Period</label>


                        <div class="periodSelector">

                            <!--periodValues must correspond with the name of the array-->

                            <select ng-model="selected.period" ng-options="period.period for period in periodValues">
                                <option value="" disabled>Select Month</option>


                            </select>   <!-- select ng-model  -->
                        </div><!--close periodselector-->
                    </div><!--Div class form-group-->
                </div><!--Div class: Month Select-->
            </div><!--Div class: Panel Body-->
        </div><!--Div class panel: Default-->
    </div><!--Div class col-md-12-->
</div><!--Div class: Row-->
<!--Customer report Generator-->
<!--LynchReport Generator-->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways you can achieve this try any of these

use a table 
    wrap your contents in one single HTML table row.

```
 <table>
  <tr>
     <td> field 1 </td>
     <td> field 2 </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

or

use `style="float:left"`  for each element you need on a single line. use proper `margin` to have enough spacing between them

```
   <div  style="float:left;margin:2px;">
        field 1
   </div>
   <div  style="float:left;margin:2px;">
        field 2
   </div>
```

Another way is to use `bootstrap` as your code already look like  you are already using that,

check this link on how to align your `divs`.    http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
   </div>
```

can very well align your code. your can change the number `6` to other values say `1-12`  for proper alignment.